# IF... ELSE... two mutually exclusive inserts INTO #temptable

Tags: t-sql, if-statement, sql-server-2012, compiler-errors, temp-tables

I need to insert either set A or set B of records into a #temptable, depending on certain condition

My pseudo-code:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#t1') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #t1;

IF {some-condition}
  SELECT {columns}
  INTO #t1 
  FROM {some-big-table}
  WHERE {some-filter}
ELSE
  SELECT {columns}
  INTO #t1
  FROM {some-other-big-table}
  WHERE {some-other-filter}
```

The two SELECTs above are exclusive (guaranteed by the ELSE operator). However, SQL compiler tries to outsmart me and throws the following message:

```
There is already an object named '#t1' in the database.
```

My idea of "fixing" this is to create #t1 upfront and then executing a simple INSERT INTO (instead of SELECT... INTO). But I like minimalism and am wondering whether this can be achieved in an easier way i.e. without explicit CREATE TABLE #t1 upfront.

*Btw why is it NOT giving me an error on a conditional DROP TABLE in the first line? Just wondering.*

Comment: To answer your last question; the `DROP TABLE #t1` will only be executed if the `IF`-statement returns true, i.e. the table exists. As you say you want to simplify, you could re-write that to `IF EXISTS(OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#t1')) DROP TABLE #t1;`.

Comment: @PatrikBirgersson I get it! However, I wasn't wondering how to simplify that particular line of code. It was more about inconsistency between not being able to run a conditional SELECT ... INTO #temptable... in a branched IF...ELSE block versus being able to do a conditional DROP of a #temptable in the first line. Rajesh's reply clears all my doubts here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have 2 temp tables with the same name in a single SQL batch. One of the MSDN article says "If more than one temporary table is created inside a single stored procedure or batch, they must have different names". You can have this logic with 2 different temp tables or table variable/temp table declared outside the IF-Else block.

Answer (score 0):

Using a Dyamic sql we can handle this situation. As a developoer its not a good practice. Best to use table variable or temp table.

```
IF 1=2
BEGIN
EXEC ('SELECT 1 ID INTO #TEMP1
SELECT * FROM #TEMP1
')
END
ELSE
EXEC ('SELECT 2 ID INTO #TEMP1
SELECT * FROM #TEMP1    
')
```

Comment: Thanks, this would definitely work to a certain point i.e. it would populate the #temp and then return all its rows. However, I am using #temp table in subsequent queries which makes your approach not suitable for my case. I ended up with creating a #temp table upfront and populating it with INSERT INTO...